# How to write a async middleware in KOA 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, koa, koa2

I want to resolve a promise and then render a view like so in Koa 2.

```
async function render(ctx, next) {
  // wait for some async action to finish
  await new Promise((resolve) => { 
   setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
  })
  // then, send response
  ctx.type = 'text/html'
  ctx.body = 'some response'
  await next()
}
```

However when I do this, the server does not send any response (browser keeps waiting for a response, and times out). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you declare this function to be used by koa? `koa.use(render)` ?

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Yes, i'm exporting this middleware and doing a `const app = new Koa(); app.use(render)`

Comment: just curios if you do `koa.use((ctx, next) => render(ctx, next))` same problem?

Comment: nevermind, I just replicated your example on a brand simple koa seed (https://github.com/chentsulin/simple-koa2-example) and works perfectly... the problem must reside somewhere else. What other middleware do you have in the app? Also: how do you start the server? And what version of node are you using?

Comment: @OvidiuDolha I too tried to use the simple-koa example you linked to. Adding a :
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 10000)
    })
to the router.js file causes immediate return i.e. for some reason, the await of 10 seconds does not occur

Comment: I'm on node v7.x and starting server using `app.listen(port)` to start the server.

Comment: Using the router is something else - i was talking about just a basic koa - i.e. removed router and other middleware and just add the app.use(render) in server.js works as expected... So in the end, you are using also koa-router in your app also an want to do the above code in a router function? Or you're just using koa and no other middleware?

Comment: Unfortunately my setup is a little complex, where I'm transcompiling this middleware to es5 using webpack. I'm trying to reduce the variables and see if I can get a minimal subset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132674/discussion-between-user3210476-and-ovidiu-dolha).

Answer (score 9):

I realize that I'm a couple months late here, but I stumbled upon the same issue just now and discovered that in order for a given middleware to be able to wait for async executions, all of the preceding middleware has to `await next()`, as opposed to just `next()`. Make sure to verify that, seems obvious in hindsight.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh god finally, after hours of searching. Thank you so much!

Comment: ugh.. facepalm! (tx!)

Answer (score 1):

So, I took your code and created a little app:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

async function render(ctx, next) {
  // wait for some async action to finish
  await new Promise((resolve) => { 
   setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
  })
  // then, send response
  ctx.type = 'text/html'
  ctx.body = 'some response'
  await next()
}

app.use(render);

app.listen(3000);
```

This works out of the box this way ... no changes needed. So it seems, the way you "used" your `render` function was somehow not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The way I write middleware is pretty similar with @Sebastian:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

const render = async(ctx, next) {
    // wait for some async action to finish
    await new Promise((resolve) => { 
        setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
    });
    // then, send response
    ctx.type = 'text/html';
    ctx.body = 'some response';

    await next();
}

app.use(render);
....
```

hope it helps you